# How to authenticate with HttpRepl to test protected api's?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

In order to test the Azure DevOp API,

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/itemsbatch?api-version=6.0
```

we need to log in first.

> HTTP/1.1 203 Non-Authoritative Information

What is the best way to handle authentication in this API testing?
Add tokens in the request headers?

Answer (score 1):

After you get JWT you can use it in the command line like below:

```
set header Authorization "bearer <TOKEN VALUE>"
```

You can see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/http-repl/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#set-http-request-headers

Answer (score 0):

To test the REST API, you need either Testing Tool to drive the API or writing down your own code.

Rest API can be tested with tools like:

- [Advanced Rest Client](https://install.advancedrestclient.com/install)
- [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

[image]

To write your own code, you could refer to the following sample:

```
public static async void GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        var personalaccesstoken = "PAT_FROM_WEBSITE";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
                        "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```